# C# Stop process started by my own process

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, process, debian

I made a launcher for my ARK Server where I can easily change my settings and start.
I start the server with this:

```
Process serverprocess = new Process();
serverprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(serverpath);
serverprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = launch;
serverprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
serverprocess.Start();
serverprocess.WaitForExit();
```

But when I press CTRL+C it doesn't wait until the ARK Server stops, it still runs in background while my app is killed.
I did some testing, the server recieves the shutdown signal and stops (which takes some time, espeically when the server isn't fully started). But when it takes time to stop the server is still running while my app already closed.
Doublepressing CTRL+C will kill the server but since the first press already brings me out of the console I'm unable to doublepress.
Any idea how I can prevent my app from beeing closed while still stopping the ARK server?
Adding `Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;` will stop the server from even recieving the signal.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to rely on CTRL + C to safely close a program. You should consider implementing something to close everything properly. Why not waiting for the user to write "exit" or something?

Comment: Well because you stop the ark server by pressing CTRL+C once and kills it by pressing it twice. Thats how they made it (Avorion also stops the server with CTRL+C). typing "exit" would require you to open a RCON connection and sendig it over there.

Comment: Just implement it in your program and when the user type "exit", call `serverprocess.Close();` then wait for it to exit. CTRL+C kill your program so you cannot properly close your child process.

Comment: Don't work, posted under your answer. Whycan't i simply pass the CTRL+C to my child process?

Answer (score 0):

My test is ok

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";//sh 
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " && echo 'OK'\""; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
proc.Start();

Comment: Did you tried this with an ARK server? it behaved different then a bash script.
Ark server is still running in background after pressing CTRL+C

Answer (score 0):

You should properly close your program for it to close properly your server. Here you go:

```cs
var serverProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(serverpath),
    Arguments = launch,
    UseShellExecute = false
});

while (Console.ReadLine() != "exit")
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}

serverProcess.Close();
```

Comment: serverprocess.Close();
serverprocess.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
will give me an exception:

Comment: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.                                                                                                                                               at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetWaitState()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExitCore(Int32 milliseconds)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit()
   at ARKLauncher.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: serverprocess.WaitForExit();

Comment: Oh yeah serverProcess.Close already have .WaitForExit, just remove that line I will update my answer.

Comment: sadly still no. still need to kill the server with htop.

Comment: Describe what happen, I can't help you if you don't give me information...

Comment: I press my key, I run serverprocess.Close(). In console I come back to the default where I can run commands and start programs, I open htop and ARK's process tree is still active but it'S no longer attached to the screen session I'm running my servers in.

Comment: Have you tried with .Kill instead? I did not notice that you run everything in a linux environment

Comment: yes but kill kills the server. So he doesn'T recieve a stop command and won't save the world :/
Currently I try to connect with RCON and send the stop command this way...